# Migration version 20130915081732 already registered with class Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Version

Tags: symfony, doctrine-migrations

I just want to generate a new migration class

```
app/console doctrine:migrations:status

[Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\MigrationException]
Migration version 20130915081732 already registered with class Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Version
```

My config.yml looks like

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name:   %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Project/Migrations
    namespace:  Project\Migrations
    table_name: doctrine_migration_versions
    name:       Project Migrations
```

The paths and namespace are correct but there are already migrations in this folder (also the version 20130915081732).
I don't know what's wrong, maybe you can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Background: It is a project migrated from Silex. And there was an old migration.xml in the doc root which had a wrong configuration. After deleting this file everything worked.